How to dynamic change component of idea setting dialog
In my IDEA plugin, I hava implement the Configurable to create a settings dialog.
In the method createComponent, I hava create a component A contains a JBCheckBox, it use an actionListener, when it is choosed, the component will remove two LabeledComponent in A.
    @Override
    public @Nullable JComponent createComponent() {
        component = new MySettingsComponent();
        panel = component.getConfigPanel();
        // 添加监听动作并重绘页面
        component.getMyCheckBox().addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
          if (component.isChecked()) {
            Container container = component.getFieldA().getParent();
            if (container != null) {
              container.remove(component.getFieldB()); // remove filedB and successed
            }
          } else {
            // try to re-add fieldB or re-create panel
          }
          Container parent = panel.getParent();
          parent.revalidate();
          parent.repaint();
        });
        return panel;

filedA、fieldB are LabeledComponent.
When I was going to add the removed LabeledComponent to A, the layout and position can not be controlled.
Is there any way to solve this? Or is there a way to re-create the component? Or how can I re-open the settings page?

open a new dialog
a new dialog comes with fieldB, but the old one still exists and didn't change
ShowSettingsUtil.getInstance().showSettingsDialog(project, MyConfigurable.class);

get the container and add the removed component
but the removedField stays on the top of the panel


Container container = component.myField().getParent();
container.add(removedField, 7); // 7 is the old index of fieldB

I alse tried to remove all components in this panel and re add all components, but they all lined in a row.
or create new panel and reassign to old panel, but the lable title keeps while no lableTextField.
